How to add a simple RISCV intrinsic in LLVM
I have a simple scalar instruction which I added to LLVM, which takes two inputs from GPR and writes the output also to GPR. I can compile C code using inline assembly for the new instruction. I would like to add it as an intrinsic.
something like:
int a, b,c;
a= _myinstruction(b,c); // in C
so that LLVM will produce assembly with my instruction
myinstruction a0,a1,a2
I looked into intrinsics for vector extension but they include many parameters such as SEW, LMUL, tale type
I would like something simpler
Does someone know how to add a simple intrinsic to LLVM?
